# How to make analytical table display more rows SAP FIORI

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori, cds

I made a SAP Fiori app from template with an analytical table in it.
The table however only displays 4 rows. It looks really small.
Im looking for a way to make the table show maybe 10 rows or something.
Here is a picture of the table:

As you can see the table only displays 4 rows

[image: 1]

Since the app was created from template there is no view or controller in the UI5 webide.
I have been looking for cds annotations, xml annotations or anything but wasnt able to find anything usefull.
Any help is much appreciated.
If someone can explain how to make a table show more rows with a non-template project in the webide this would also be appreciated.

Comment: Right Click your project in Web IDE and open it with the "SAPUI5 Visual Editor". Focus your table. You should be able to adjust some propertys like `visibleRowCount`, `minAutoRowCount`... [See here](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_Web_IDE/825270ffffe74d9f988a0f0066ad59f0/6fae0cd0678c4ebe85ac743a69b2886c.html?locale=en-US)